# Why laravel/ui is not accepted?

Tags: laravel

I try to install laravel/ui with command

> composer require laravel/ui:^2.4

laravel/ui[v2.4.0, ..., v2.4.1] require php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.1.2) does not satisfy that requirement.

My php version is 8.1.2:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mxaBm.png)

Answer (score 1):

laravel/ui 2.4 is compatible with older php version. either install newest laravel/ui via `composer require laravel/ui` command, or downgrade php.

Comment: For a fuller picture. Laravel UI 2.4 does not work for PHP 8+ and while Laravel UI 2.5 **does** work and would normally be the one selected (because the version constraint is `^2.4`)  it cannot be installed because that requires Laravel 7 and OP seems to be using an older version of Laravel